# AWS Chime Screen Share in ipad safari - attendees cannot hear audio of the video played

Tags: ipad, safari, screensharing, aws-chime-sdk, amazon-chime

I have some questions for AWS CHime as we wanted to build a video calling application.

1. If we are using iPad safari and using AWS Chime for video calls can I share my screen during a video call?

For us, it's not working.

2. Then we tried to make an iOS Native App and tried to use AWS CHime SDK. This time screen share worked but if I share my screen and play a video on youtube another user can only see the video he cannot hear any audio of that played video.

I am tired of contacting the AWS Chime support team. They never answer any of the questions instead they send me this and then do not respond. I regret using AWS Chime. It has lots of issues. Pathetic library.

1. When did the issue first occur.
2. What is the Meeting ID of the meeting when users experienced this issue.
3. Could you please confirm that the issue is isolated to the Safari browser-based application?
4. Please provide the current Safari version, which can be found by following the steps in the following documentation [1]

Answer (score 1):

Apologies on your AWS support experience. Content Share Audio is not yet supported in Amazon Chime SDK for iOS as of 5/4/2021.
This is on our roadmap and planned for future releases. Feel free to open an issue in our [iOS GitHub repo](https://github.com/aws/amazon-chime-sdk-ios/) to track this feature request.